# Unable to add custom header to HttpService (Angular v4)

Tags: angular, dropwizard

I'm attempting to add a custom header to a request in an angular (v4) application by extending the default Http class and overriding the request() method to append a specific authorization custom header. The class looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptionsArgs, Request, Response, ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthToken } from '../authentication/auth-token';


@Injectable()
export class ZHttpService extends Http {

  private HEADER_AUTHORIZATION: string = 'X-Z-AUTHORIZATION';

  constructor(protected backend: ConnectionBackend, protected defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  private setCustomHeaders(options?: RequestOptionsArgs):RequestOptionsArgs{
    if(!options) {
      options = new RequestOptions({});
    }

    let authTokenJSON = localStorage.getItem("z-auth-token");

    if(authTokenJSON) {
      if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers();
      }

      let authToken: AuthToken = JSON.parse(authTokenJSON);
      options.headers.append(this.HEADER_AUTHORIZATION, `${authToken.token}`);
    }
    return options;
  }

  request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    options = this.setCustomHeaders(options);
    return super.request(url, options).catch(this.catchAuthError(this));
  }

  private catchAuthError (self: ZHttpService) {
    return (res: Response) => {
      console.log(res);
      if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403) {
        console.log(res);
      }
      return Observable.throw(res);
    };
  }

  public isAuthenticated() {
    return localStorage.getItem("z-auth-token") != null;
  }
}
```

The class using this custom http service simply does the following (in this instance):

```
...
constructor (private http: ZHttpService) {}

  getAccount(): Observable<Account> {
    return this.http.get(this.accountUrl)
      .map(this.parseAccount)
      .catch(this.handleError); 
  }
...
```

The token is being successfully retrieved and this code is being executed. However on the outgoing request there is no custom header present.

CORS is configured on the server side (DropWizard) as follows:

```
// Cross Origin Policy Configuration
final FilterRegistration.Dynamic corsFilterConfig = environment.servlets().addFilter("CORS", CrossOriginFilter.class);
corsFilterConfig.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_ORIGINS_PARAM, "*");
corsFilterConfig.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_HEADERS_PARAM, "X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Origin");
corsFilterConfig.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.EXPOSED_HEADERS_PARAM, "X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Origin");
corsFilterConfig.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_METHODS_PARAM, "OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,HEAD");

// Cors URL Mapping
corsFilterConfig.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), true, "*");

// Restriction to Permit Unauthenticated Preflight Responses
corsFilterConfig.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.CHAIN_PREFLIGHT_PARAM, Boolean.FALSE.toString());
```

When the request is made from the angular application the following headers are present.

[image: Request Headers]

The version of Angular being used is recent, here's the ng --version output.

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.3
node: 6.10.2
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.1.2
@angular/animations/browser: undefined
@angular/common: 4.1.2
@angular/compiler: 4.1.2
@angular/core: 4.1.2
@angular/forms: 4.1.2
@angular/http: 4.1.2
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.5
@angular/platform-browser: 4.1.2
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.2
@angular/platform-browser/animations: undefined
@angular/router: 4.1.2
@angular/cli: 1.0.3
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.2
```

Is there something fundamental I'm doing incorrectly? Is this a bug with Angular? Is my DropWizard configuration incorrect?

It should be noted that if I use PostMan to make the same request (with the header added in postman) the service works as expected.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the get method in your `ZHttpService`?

Comment: Have you checked if `z-auth-token` was present and had a value in your local storage?

Comment: @Supamiu Yes, the console.Log() validates that the method is invoked and the token is present and fetched.

Comment: @echonax is it required? I was under the impression all methods (GET, POST, PUT) are a subset of request and invoking the default get by extension in the base Http class would be sufficient. Is this not the case? I will try it either way.

Comment: @Ryan but you are using `setCustomHeaders` inside your `request` method. If you call `get` from the super class, the super class will use its own `request` instead. Am I wrong? https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/http/src/http.ts#L130

Comment: @echonax, that's a good point and would definitely be the case. I will adjust that now and try again.

Comment: @echonax this did solve the issue, you were correct. Running into an issue where CORS must not be configured properly now, as any request from my Angular application (such as POST {host}/api/login) simply sends an OPTIONS request and gets a 200 OK response and ends there.

Comment: @Ryan cool, I'll provide it as an answer then :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `setCustomHeaders` inside your `request` method. However, if you call `get` from the super class, the super class will use its own `request` instead. So you need to override the `get` method too.